# Does the group of permutations of $\omega$ with finite supports interpret arithmetic?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Does the group $G$ of permutation of $\omega$ of finite support interpret $\Bbb N = (\omega, +, \cdot, <, 0, 1)$? I hear about groups that do not interpret bad combinatorial structures all the time, but I am not familiar with groups that do interpret bad structures.  The said group $G$ seems bad enough to possibly interpret $\Bbb N$; does it really do so?

Comment: What does "group interprets" combinatorial structure or arithmetic mean?

Comment: @Conifold I assume it means "interpret" in the [model-theoretic sense of the term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(model_theory)).

Comment: Is it even clear that $(\omega, \cdot, 0, 1)$ can be interpreted? Getting $2\cdot2=4$ seems challenging.

Comment: I think this would be worth asking on MathOverflow.